# How to use 'keys' in a dictionary as wildcard patterns in matching filenames?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to open the files whose name contains a pattern - which is the key value stored in a dictionary (key values in the dictionary are the patterns I'm trying to match in the file name).

I'm currently using `glob.blob` to match the pattern in the file name. The name of my dictionary is "xd". So, I want to implement something like this:

```py
for key in xd :
    for name in glob.glob(*key*):
        file = open ('name','w')
```

I'm getting invalid syntax error here

I want to be able to open all the files which have the 'key' in their name and perform text addition in those files. Could someone please tell me if there is a way of doing this?

Comment: Please show us the actual code. You've indicated that your code is "something like this" but we need to see the real thing if we're going to help you in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob.glob()` expects a `str` parameter, so you'll need to make a string out of the wildcards with `key` included. I'd also suggest opening files using `with` so you don't forget to close the file descriptor.

```py
for key in xd:
    for name in glob.glob(f"*{key}*"):
        with open(name, 'w')
            ...
```